# Indexing and searching French text with diacritics in Lucene

Tags: unicode, encoding, lucene, diacritics

I am using Lucene Search.

I have uploaded a French file (french.txt) with the following content.

```
multimédia francophone pour l'enseignement du français langue étrangère
```

If I search for `francophone` then it shows the file in the search result. But when I search for `multimédia` or `français` or `étrangère`, it does not show any results.

I have tried to use `org.apache.lucene.analysis.fr.FrenchAnalyzer`, but it is still not working.

How can we search French words such as those above?

Comment: I assume you have read [this](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/IndexingOtherLanguages)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory in the analyzers for the field where this text is indexed? Make sure that if you have it for the index analyzer, you also have it for the query analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

BTW. If you are using ISOLatin1AccentFilter note that it was deprecated in favor of ASCIIFoldingFilter

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have 2 options:

1. Index and search your French files with Snowball analyzer for French
2. Index your French docs as usual, but search with FuzzyQuery (not very accurate, but may be enough in your particular case).